# warning on creating multiple elements using React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I use `React.createElement` to create elements with dynamic view:

```
{list && list.length !== 0 ?
    list.map((model, i) =>
        React.createElement(ListRow, {
            key: i,
            model,
            ...rowProps,

            onEdit: () => this.onEdit(model),
            onDelete: () => this.onDelete(model)
    })) : null
}
```

This works fine for me, but I get this warning in console:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. See *here shold be link* for more information.
    in EditableList (created by Connect(EditableList))
    in Connect(EditableList) (created by CreateInvoiceFormView)
```

I get this warning even if `list.length === 0`< and have no idea why this happens. 
I've tried to generate id's, that didn't help.

Here is whole component code:

```
class EditableList extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
    const {name, dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(createList(name));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    const {name, dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(destroyList(name));
}

onAdd(item) {
    const {dispatch, name} = this.props;
    dispatch(openPopup(name, item));
}

onEdit(item) {
    const {dispatch, name} = this.props;
    dispatch(editItem(name, item));
    dispatch(openPopup(name, item));
}

onDelete(item) {
    const {dispatch, name} = this.props;
    dispatch(deleteItem(name, item));
}

render() {
    const {ListRow, list, rowProps, title} = this.props;

    return [
        <SectionTitleView title={title} add onClick={() => this.onAdd()}/>,
        <div>{list && list.length !== 0 ? list.map((model, i) =>
            React.createElement(ListRow, {
                key: i,
                model,
                ...rowProps,

                onEdit: () => this.onEdit(model),
                onDelete: () => this.onDelete(model)
            })) : null
        }
        </div>];
}
}
```

I searched for this problem in here on stack by couldn't fing anything similar, and I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Please let me know, if I don't provide enough information for this issue.

Comment: Have you seen **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)** ?

Comment: @alp I read it, just now and as you can see, there are unique keys passed to components, the problem is I get this warning even if there is no components rendered using React.createElement yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using latest syntax of react v16.0, It requires you to add keys to all the elements. Since your `SectionTitleView` element does not have the `key` attribute you are getting this error.

For more details please refer:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings

Alternatively, you can also wrap your components inside a `<div>` in the render function.